# openssl sha1 message digest not matching with NIST vector input?

Tags: openssl, sha-1, nist

When I call openssl sha1 from the command line

```
 echo "00" | xxd -r -p | openssl dgst -sha1
```

the output I am receive is

```
(stdin)= 5ba93c9db0cff93f52b521d7420e43f6eda2784f
```

But the [NIST Vector](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cavp/secure-hashing.html#shavs) output is:

```
 MD = da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709
```

Can anyone please explain this?

Comment: for reference, 5ba93c9db0cff93f52b521d7420e43f6eda2784f is the correct result for a 1 byte input of 0x00

Comment: Almost cross-posted: [Getting Message Digest from SHA1 message](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43676496/1816580)

Comment: Note you need to use `-n` with `echo` to prevent adding a trailing new line. You can test this by writing in the terminal `$ echo 'foo'` and `$ echo -n 'foo'`.

Answer (score 4):

You read the testvector incorrectly.

I assume you are referring to the following part of the file `SHA1ShortMsg.rsp` of the FIPS 180-4 vectors:

```
[L = 20]

Len = 0 
Msg = 00 
MD = da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709
```

This test vector has length 0, so the specified hash is for an empty message and not for a single zero byte. This openssl command shows the correct result.

> $ echo -n ""|openssl dgst -sha1
>   (stdin)= da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709

Comment: when the input is not of len 0                                                                                                Len = 2
Msg = 40
MD = ec6b39952e1a3ec3ab3507185cf756181c84bbe2                               The result is echo -n "\x40" | openssl dgst -sha1
(stdin)= 798f17bb2ad6914266daf60dc6e8e2571d779a39
echo -n "40" | xxd -r -p | openssl dgst -sha1
(stdin)= 9a78211436f6d425ec38f5c4e02270801f3524f8
echo -n "40" | openssl dgst -sha1
(stdin)= af3e133428b9e25c55bc59fe534248e6a0c0f17b
None are matching with the result

Comment: @user3405360 I can't find that example [here](https://github.com/AtmelCSO/cryptoauth-openssl-engine/blob/master/engine_atecc/cryptoauthlib/test/sha-byte-test-vectors/SHA1ShortMsg.rsp), but for example the second one works: `printf "\x36" | openssl dgst -sha1` gives `(stdin)= c1dfd96eea8cc2b62785275bca38ac261256e278`

Comment: I am checking for BIT oriented implementations but your example is for BYTE oriented implementation

Comment: `openssl dgst` can only process full bytes.